# INNER JOIN on a Sub Query

Tags: sql, join

I have a list of tasks in a table called dbo.Task

In the database, each Task can have 1 or more rows in the TaskLine table.

TaskLine has a TaskID to related the Tasklines to the Task.

A TaskLine has a column called TaskHeadingTypeID

I need to return all the tasks, joined to the LAST TaskLine for that Task.

In english, I need to display a task, with the latest TaskLine heading. So, I basically need to join to the TaskLine table, like this (which, is incorrect and maybe inefficient, but hopefully shows what I am trying to do)

```
SELECT *
  FROM @Results r
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT TOP 1 TaskID, TaskHeadingTypeID FROM dbo.TaskLine
      ORDER BY TaskLineID DESC
    ) tl
      ON tl.TaskID = r.TaskID
```

However, the issue is, the sub query only brings back the last TaskLine row, which is incorrect.

Edit:

At the moment, it's 'Working' like the code below, but it seems highly inefficient, because for each task row, it has to run two extra queries. And they're both on the same table, just slightly different columns in that table:

(An extract of the columns in the SELECT cause)

```
 SELECT TaskStatusID,
  TaskStatus,
  (SELECT TOP 1 TaskHeadingTypeID FROM dbo.TaskLine
    WHERE TaskID = r.TaskID
  ORDER BY TaskLineID DESC) AS TaskHeadingID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 LongName FROM dbo.TaskLine tl
    INNER JOIN ref.TaskHeadingType tht
      ON tht.TaskHeadingTypeID = tl.TaskHeadingTypeID
    WHERE TaskID = r.TaskID
  ORDER BY TaskLineID DESC) AS TaskHeading,
  PersonInCareID, 
  ICMSPartyID, 
  CarerID.... FROM...
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the ideas and comments below, I have ended up with this, using CTE:

```
;WITH ValidTaskLines (RowNumber, TaskID, TaskHeadingTypeID, TaskHeadingType)
  AS
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY tl.TaskID, tl.TaskHeadingTypeID ORDER BY tl.TaskLineID) AS RowNumber,
        tl.TaskID, 
        tl.TaskHeadingTypeID, 
        LongName AS TaskHeadingType
      FROM dbo.TaskLine tl
      INNER JOIN ref.TaskHeadingType tht
      ON tht.TaskHeadingTypeID = tl.TaskHeadingTypeID
    )

  SELECT AssignedByBusinessUserID, 
      BusinessUserID, 
      LoginName, 
      Comments, 
      r.CreateDate, 
      r.CreateUser, 
      r.Deleted, 
      r.Version,
      IcmsBusinessUserID, 
      r.LastUpdateDate, 
      r.LastUpdateUser,
      OverrrideApprovalBusinessUserID, 
      PlacementID, 
      r.TaskID, 
      TaskPriorityTypeID,
      TaskPriorityCode,
      TaskPriorityType,
            TaskStatusID,
      TaskStatus,
      vtl.TaskHeadingTypeID AS TaskHeadingID,
      vtl.TaskHeadingType AS TaskHeading,
      PersonInCareID, 
      ICMSPartyID, 
      CarerID, 
      ICMSCarerEntityID, 
      StartDate, 
      EndDate 
  FROM @Results r
  INNER JOIN ValidTaskLines vtl
    ON vtl.TaskID = r.TaskID
    AND vtl.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: You want to JOIN with the latest from each group?

Comment: @Mihai - How would that be done?

Comment: Using CTE, ROW_NUMBER() and JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Results r
INNER JOIN (SELECT TaskID
                 , TaskHeadingTypeID
                 , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TaskID, TaskHeadingTypeID ORDER BY TAskLineID DESC) RN
            FROM dbo.TaskLine
           ) tl
 ON tl.TaskID = r.TaskID
 AND t1.RN = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY Some_Date`  then for each unique date value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

You may need to adjust the `PARTITION BY` to suit your query, run the subquery by itself to get an idea of how the `ROW_NUMBER()` works.